# Images randomly doing a bungee jump upon resize of browser window

Tags: jquery, html, browser, window-resize

The most mysterious issue I have come across so far. Visit the site I'm currently designing: http://ftfranes.com/mliad2/

Then just resize your browser window once the page is loaded. You will notice that the images will instantly jump further down the page. I would lie if I told you that I have any clue about what that is causing this so I am turning to someone here that might simply be more intelligent than me.

Comment: You have a lot of scripts on that page, and one of them is probably the culprit. Try disabling them one by one to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's seems to be two problematic containers, as I see it, regarding your floated containers. Both `.sidebar-right-twitter` and `.projects` take up full width, so `.projects` (containing your thumbnails) is being pushed below `.sidebar-right-twitter` when they should be side-by-side.

```
.side-bar-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 705px;  /* Reduce a lot or omit entirely? */
  :
}

.projects {
  float: left;
  width: 940px;  /* Reduce to nearer 700px */
  :
}
```

Making these changes to the CSS appears to resolve the issue in Chrome. (I did, however, need to resize the window again in order to make it 'jump back'.)

**EDIT**

The 2nd issue of the small jump... (The `H2` appears to have been a red herring / coincidence.)

When you resize the window some *script* is applying `top:368px` to `#grid_clone`. And this appears to be pushing the thumbnails container down a bit too far. A real hack is to apply `margin-top:-28px;` on this element in the CSS to counteract this extra jump.

I suspect you will need to apply `margin-top:-28px;` to both elements otherwise they will not align.

Continued in the comments...

Comment: Yup, that fixed everything, I reduced the projects to 700px and omitted the side-bar-right's margin-left. Thank you very much brother.

Comment: Or let me resay that, it appears that there is still one issue left. If you look at the site now and resize, you will notice that it still makes a more minor jump, do you know the cause of this?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson This second issue appears to be caused by the "Latest Tweets" `H2`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However can you please tell me how I go about this. I tried setting "width:100%" on H2 but it broke the filter and it still jumped upon resize. Is there any chance that you can give me some more pointers?

Comment: Also, I have updated the H2 now with "width:100%", if you resize the window, you will see that it still does the small jump.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I had actually added `width:100%` in typography.css (as opposed to style.css), but I think you can change that back - it doesn't appear to be the cause of the 2nd problem afterall. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Cheers for the update. Will you have the chance to debug this so that I can finally have this site finished? I don't know what to offer you, maybe I'll buy you a pint if we cross paths in Reading?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - Have you tried the `margin-top:-28px` hack I mention? This does actually appear to resolve the immediate problem. I've updated my answer with some more notes.

Comment: The image-grid is connected with the filter menu, the filter will not work without it. Nevertheless, I added -28px for margin-top in the CSS for both image-grid and grid_clone but same problem is there. You can have a look to confirm.

Comment: I solved the issue with a rather dumb hack, added a <div style="height:Xpx;"></div> in the HTML prior to these divs to level it. Thank you very much regardless for your assistance, I have labeled this answer as correct.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - OK change the `margin-top` back! ;) I think I'm seeing the underlying cause. I don't think it is a script issue after all. The `top:368px` that is being calculated is a result of the `margin-bottom:40px` on `.filter_container`. You are somewhat compensating for this with `margin-top:-24px` on `.sidebar_right_twitter`. Still looking at a fix...

Comment: Excellent, fingers crossed you will find a fix for it.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes, I see that adding that `div` would probably resolve the jump. And I think removing the `margin-top:-24px` on `.sidebar_right_twitter` might also solve the problem? (Maybe) Presumably there is now a slightly larger gap below the filter line? Try reducing the `margin-bottom` on `.filter_container` to close the gap...?

Answer (score 0):

ul with id grid_clone is getting top:845px when we resize, because it is positioned absolutely it is going to bottom leaving 845px on top. Is it any plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a css problem. `#image-grid` floats left as well as `.sidebar_right_twitter`. But an element must have enough space to float. If not it will jump to the next row. So by resizing the window, the div does not have enough space anymore and goes to the next row.

So if you want to elements floating next to each other you will need a container:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <div class="floatLeft">
    </div>
    <div class="floatRight">
    </div>
</div>
```

Be sure to give the floating divs a width, which shoul not exceed the given space.

Answer (score 0):

Re-arrange your content structure, you need to put your `<ul>` above the div for the right side bar. They are both set to float left, so you will want the element on the left to be first.

Edit*

Your grid is displayed in an unordered list - `<ul>` which is created after the `<div>` tag that the sidebar is contained in. I believe that a combination of removing the mentioned positioning code and improper floats will fix your problem. It's likely that the `<ul>` doesn't even need a float, based on the positioning assigned to it by your scripts.

Play around with firebug, you may be resistant at first but it is a MUST have for anyone working with HTML and CSS

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your answer?